# json encode MongoDB documents for Sphinx search?

Tags: mongodb, sphinx

Since I am using PHP, I am thinking of the simple way for just json_encode the whole document and save it in a MySQL column, and from MySQL makes Sphinx index.

This however seems crude and I wonder if others had come across a better solution?

Answer (score 1):

I personally pick out my parts and actually save them to a schema in MySQL, Sphinx cannot parse out and query correctly on a string field that is actually representing a document. It is like doing the same in MongoDB or MySQL normal, it won't work very well and the FTS index will not understand that it is a Document but instead will just see it as a String.

Comment: I agree. Just to clarify, JSON support in sphinx, only makes attributes. Sphinx cant extract fields from JSON data - its fields that are actully full-text searchable.

Comment: @barryhunter didn't know about the attributes bit, that's good to know

Comment: @barryhunter Thank you for mentioning the JSON support in sphinx. For example I save the following as string {"name":"john","age":"13"} in a mysql field. Would you mind clarifying more on "Sphinx cant extract fields from JSON data"?

Comment: Just that. You couldnt easily use sphinx to search the 'name' value in the json. Fields are what is searchable. Sphinx couldnt make a field direct form that json string. It COULD make a attribute, but you can't full-text search attributes.